# Why my div tag is not showing correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code which is working fine in firefox, but when I want to see it from mobile it cuts the end of some of my div tags. And they are not showing at all. Am I missing something? please see the following:

```
<div class="banner-bg">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" poster="wall_icons/my.jpg" width="100%" loop>
        <source src="srix.mp4" type="video/mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    <div class="banner">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="logo wow fadeInRight" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="top-menu">
                <span class="menu"></span>
                <ul class="cl-effect-1">
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#home">Main</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#brief">Text1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#features">Text2</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#screenshots">Text3</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#testimonial">Text4</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#contact">Text5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- script-for-menu -->
            <script>
                $("span.menu").click(function () {
                    $("ul.cl-effect-1").slideToggle(300, function () {
                        // Animation complete.
                    });
                });
            </script>
            <!-- script-for-menu -->
        </div>
        <div class="banner-text wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
            <h1>Welcome</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="booking-form">
            <!---strat-date-piker---->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css"/>
            <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $("#datepicker,#datepicker1").datepicker();
                });
            </script>
            <!---/End-date-piker---->
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/JFGrid.css"/>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/JFFormStyle-1.css"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JFCore.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/JFForms.js"></script>
            <!-- Set here the key for your domain in order to hide the watermark on the web server -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (function () {
                    JC.init({
                        domainKey: ''
                    });
                })();
            </script>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div class="booking_room">
                        <div class="reservation">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="span1_of_1 right">
                                    <h5>Form</h5>
                                    <div class="book_date">
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="City" required="">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="span1_of_1 right">
                                    <h5>To</h5>
                                    <div class="book_date">
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="ToCity" required="">
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="span1_of_1 right">
                                    <h5>Enter</h5>
                                    <div class="book_date">
                                        <form>
                                            <input class="date" id="datepicker" type="text" value="2/04/2015" onfocus="this.value = '';"
                                                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '2/04/2015';}" required=>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="span1_of_1 right">
                                    <h5>Text1 </h5>
                                    <div class="book_date">
                                        <form>
                                            <input class="date" id="datepicker1" type="text" value="22/08/2015" onfocus="this.value = '';"
                                                   onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '22/08/2015';}" required=>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="span1_of_1">
                                    <h5>Class</h5>
                                    <!----------start section_room----------->
                                    <div class="section_room">
                                        <select id="country" onchange="change_country(this.value)" class="frm-field required">
                                            <option value="null">Text1</option>
                                            <option value="null">Text1</option>
                                            <option value="AX">Text1</option>
                                            <option value="AX">Text1</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="span1_of_3">
                                    <div class="date_btn">
                                        <form>
                                            <input type="submit" value="Text1"/>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!---->
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="online-form">
            <a class="play-icon popup-with-zoom-anim" href="#small-dialog2">Reserve</a>
        </div>
        <div id="small-dialog2" class="mfp-hide">
            <div class="signup">
                <form>
                    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Type Depature City" required="required" pattern="([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?"/>
                    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Type Destination City" required="required" pattern="([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?"/>
                    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="2/04/2015" required="required" pattern="([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?"/>
                    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="22/08/2015" required="required" pattern="([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Book Now"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.popup-with-zoom-anim').magnificPopup({
                    type: 'inline',
                    fixedContentPos: false,
                    fixedBgPos: true,
                    overflowY: 'auto',
                    closeBtnInside: true,
                    preloader: false,
                    midClick: true,
                    removalDelay: 300,
                    mainClass: 'my-mfp-zoom-in'
                });

            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my relevant css. Please let me know if it is necessary to show other parts of my css:

```
.banner-bg {
    position: relative;
}
.banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 10%;
}
```

Comment: Could there be a media query in your CSS that's applying different styles at a typical mobile device width?  Try resizing your browser window and see if the same behavior occurs.

Comment: @SimianAngel Yes. I have also tried resizing and I see same as mobile and it doesn't show the end of div.

Comment: Most likely an `@media` style rule applying the change.  Just noticed the Twitter bootstrap tag in your question.  You'll need to overwrite the rules that are applied to your elements (i.e. add a rule with greater specificity or an identical rule that occurs after the Bootstrap declaration).  Consider using Firefox's developer tools (F12) to target your element, then scale down the browser.  The CSS affecting things should display in the Style pane.

Comment: @SimianAngel I didn't understand what you said.

Answer (score 0):

As you already wrote `<div class="online_reservation">` is not showing at all. So you must check in your style sheet file if the above rule is wrapped inside a @media query style rule.
Example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.online_reservation {
    display:none;
}
```

or at least you must provide a link to your CSS file so i can take a look and give you a more precise answer.

Comment: Please check my update I have not a online_reservation class at all.

Comment: Could you provide us a link to your css file for review?